# How to Get all nodeName inside div tag in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to get all elements `nodeName` using jQuery. I am trying, yet I am only able to get a single element's `nodeName`.

```
<div class="module">
    <p class="aa">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum <span>Test</span></p>
    <span>This span</span>
</div>
```

thanks & regards 
Venkat

Comment: `$(".module").children()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the `children()` of the `div`, and retrieve the `nodeName` property from each, like this:

```
$('.module').children().each(function() {
    var nodeName = this.nodeName;
    console.log(nodeName);
})
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/x7v253af/)

Comment: Thanks @ Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
var arr = $(".module *").map(function() {
  return this.nodeName;
}).get();
console.log(arr);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qLnazpzL/2/)

The above code will traverse through every child element(in any level) of the `module div` and push the `nodeName` to an array named `arr`

Comment: Thanks @ Anoop Joshi